Ansible prefers default vars from role over group_vars from playbook
Here are the relevant files from my ansible playbook:
group_vars/all.yml
users:
  - user1
  - user2

inventories/production.yml
ungrouped:
  hosts:
    host1.test.de:

roles/base/defaults/main.yml
users:
  - user2
  - user3
  - user4

all_users:
  user1:
    name: ..
    groups: ...
  user2: ...
  user3: ...
  user4: ...

roles/base/tasks/user.yml
- name: Create users
  ansible.builtin.user:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    password: "{{ item.shadow | default(omit) }}"
    groups: "{{ item.groups | default([]) }}"
    append: true
    shell: "/bin/bash"
    state: present
  loop: "{{ users | map('extract', all_users) }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.name }}"

roles/base/tasks/main.yml
- name: Create Users
  become: yes
  import_tasks: user.yml
  tags: user

site.yml
- name: Setup basic linux-server installation
  hosts: all
  roles:
    - base
  tags: base

Now I execute the user task:
$ ansible-playbook -i inventories/production.yml site.yml -t user

Then ansible loops over the elements from roles/base/defaults/main.yml {user2, user3, user4}. But it should loop over the elements from group_vars/all.yml {user1, user2} as stated in the docs:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence
When I delete the users variable from roles/base/defaults/main.yml all works fine and ansible loops over the users lists from group_vars/all.yml.
Am I getting something wrong here? Why is the default var used and not the group_var?

Found the problem in my site.yml:
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Include vars from base role for other roles
      include_vars:
        file: roles/base/defaults/main.yml
  tags: always

I needed that for some other roles, got to think of a way to avoid that..
